# Comparing custom object within a method

Tags: java, object, if-statement, comparison

In my app (which is an Android game - so, Java), I have a custom class called Quad which I use for my games objects.  The class creates a textured openGL quad.

I have another class called Enemy which extends Quad.

I have a method which is called from my game class and I can pass in various objects. Now, I want to do different things depending on which object was passed in, I'll try to demonstrate with some code.

```
bird = new Enemy();  //Create a bird sprite
snail = new Enemy(); //Create snail sprite

public void doSomething(Quad sprite){

    //Do work here regardless of which object was passed in
    move(object);

    if (sprite == bird){
        //Do bird specific stuff here
    }

   else if {sprite == snail}{
       //Do snail stuff here

   }

}
```

So, as you can see, I want to execute some common code regardless of the object passed into the method, (whether a bird, snail or some other object), then after the common code, there should be some object specific code run.

Now, I remember reading on one of my other questions that although this worked, it *wasn't* the correct thing to do.

Since the ratio of code is heavily skewed in the favour of the common code, (ie, the majority of the code in the method should run regardless of what the object is), it doesn't seem a great idea to create different methods for birds and snails.  Too much code duplication.

I could do this:

```
public void doSomething(Quad sprite){

    move(object);

}


 public void doBirdStuff(){

     doSomething(bird);

     //Bird specific code here

 }

public void doSnailStuff(){

     doSomething(snail);

     //Snail specific code here

 }
```

And then just call the specific object, so:

```
doSnailStuff(snail);
doBirdStuff(bird);
```

However, this just seems overly complicated and inefficient

So my question is, if comparing custom objects in this way isn't the 'Java' thing to do, how can I achieve my goal in a more acceptable way and why exactly is the first method deemed unacceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two classes (Bird and Snail) that extends Quad and use `instanceof` :

```
public void doSomething(Quad sprite){
    //Do work here regardless of which object was passed in
    move(object);

    if(sprite instanceof Bird) {
       //Do bird specific stuff here
    }
    else if {sprite instanceof Snail}{
       //Do snail stuff here
    }
 }
```

An example of how to use it :

```
public void main(){
    Bird bird = new Bird();
    Snail snail = new Snail();

    // Do something with a bird
    doSomething(bird);

    // Do something with a snail
    doSomething(snail);
}
```

## Update

Because most code isn't specific to bird/snail the best way is to use an enum that define enemy type :

```
public enum EnemyType{
    Bird,
    Snail
}
```

And use it in your Enemy class :

```
public class Enemy extends Quad{

    private EnemyType mType;

    //All other class members...

    // Constructor with type
    public Enemy(EnemyType type){
        this.mType = type;
    }

    public void doEnemyStuff(){
         if(isBird()){
         // Bird Stuff
         }
         else if(isSnail()){
         // Snail Stuff
         }
    }

    //Check if current enemy is a Bird
    public boolean isBird(){
        return mType == EnemyType.Bird;
    }

    //Check if current enemy is a Snail
    public boolean isSnail(){
        return mType == EnemyType.Snail;
    }
}
```

And finally wherever you want you can use a method like :

```
public void doSomething(Quad sprite){
    //Do work here regardless of which object was passed in
    move(object);

    if(sprite instanceof Enemy) {
       //Do enemy specific stuff here
       ((Enemy) sprite).doEnemyStuff();
    }
 }
```

With your first idea you were creating objects and keeping references to them only to make a check. Moreover it shouldn't work because the default behavior of "==" is to check equality of references ([There is](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) a little explanation about == operator).

Comment: Hi @GaetanMaisse, thanks for this, in my real project, I have an Enemy class, which extends Quad, and bird and snail are objects of this 'Enemy' class, could you show how I would use your method in my case?  I'll edit my question to show this...... (I was simplifying my code for the question).  Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this @GaëtanMaisse, when I create my object initially, I have to pass the type in?  So something like bird = new Enemy(EnemyType.Bird); (Then then import EnemyType) ?  Thanks! (I'm new to enums admittedly)

Comment: Yes, you're almost right : Enemy bird = new Enemy(EnemyType.Bird);
(Take a look [there](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html) for small intro on enum)

Comment: Yep, just updated my last comment :-)  Almost testing, but for some reason isBird(); doesn't seem to trigger - so if I say if(sprite.isBird), it doesn't return true, I'm gonna just check over it to make sure I got all the code correct.  Thanks.

Comment: It was me being silly @GaëtanMaisse , I forgot to assign mType in the constructor.  All tested and working brilliantly - I've been meaning to lean a bit about enums for a while now and this has forced my hand.  Well explained answer (makes my code a bit more readable too!) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either create a Bird and a Snail class and let the classes extend from Quad. Then you can check with

```
if (sprite instanceof Bird) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you could create a enumeration and add an attribute to `Quad`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an example of using an object oriented language (Java), but not applying object oriented concepts.

The natural object oriented way is to have the code that does "bird stuff" in a `Bird` class, and the snail specific code in a `Snail` class. Sketching this out in your example, the code shared for all enemy types would go into the `Enemy` class:

```
public class Enemy extends Quad {
    ...

    public void doSomething() {
        // common stuff
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you derive the specific enemies from this class, and implement methods with the specific behavior. These methods invoke the common behavior from their base class:

```
public class Bird extends Enemy {
    ...

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // invoke base method that does common stuff
        super.doSomething();

        // bird stuff
    }

    ...
}

public class Snail extends Enemy {
    ...

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // invoke base method that does common stuff
        super.doSomething();

        // snail stuff
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you need no ugly type checks to invoke specific behavior. You simply call the method, and the specific implementation for each type of enemy is invoked. If `badEnemy` is a variable of type `Enemy`:

```
badEnemy.doSomething();
```

This encapsulates all behavior of a specific enemy type in a class, while the rest of the code does not need to know anything about specific enemy types. When you want to introduce a new kind of enemy, you simply implement a new `Enemy` subclass with the same interface, and it will work within the system without additional changes.